# How to make a gitattribute `unspecified` again?

Tags: git, gitattributes

I have the following `.gitattributes` files:

```
.*[Dd][Aa][Tt] filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
**/Testing/**/*.[Dd][Aa][Tt] -filter -diff -merge text
```

Since the first rule matches more generally than the second rule, I want to make the attributes `filter, diff, merge` to be `unspecified`. If I remove them -> what will happen? is it now `unspecified` or is it `unset` for `git`?

Background:

- First rule -> generally all `.dat` files are binary and go to LFS
- Second rule -> an exception to rule 1, these files are `text` and dont go to LFS

Answer (score 0):

Found it here:

https://git-scm.com/docs/git-check-attr

We can write `filter=unspecified` ... which solves my problem